# Implement a class that can read a line from a given data file

Tags: java, io

Up to now I have used classes like Scanner and BufferReader/Writer, to read from a given txt file and write certain information to a txt file.

I want to implement a class that basically will do the same things as the Scanner class, meaning, will be able to parse a line of information from the file so that I can do certain stuff with this information.

My problem is I cannot find an Interface class in the java API that does this thing. And I am not sure if the Iterator interface can be used for this.
Should I write one in my own?

Thanks

Comment: Why? Why not use a Scanner or BufferedReader as a delegate?

Comment: You need to go through a good [Java I/O tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) to understand what the library code will do.  Then, when you have a specific question come back and ask here.  Also please read the [faq] and [ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: @Jim, I have already gone through the whole Java I/O tutorial, and I think I have already said it in my question that I know how to use the Scanner and BufferReader classes, and I do understand how the whole process works. And I also think my question is pretty clear too, I want to implement a class that has the same function as the Scanner class, just is an interface. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Interfaces don't 'do things'. They define methods. You don't even need an interface to implement a class, and you don't really need to implement the class either as far as I can see, unless you have requirements you haven't stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I write one in my own?

**Absolutely not**, when you can use `Scanner or BufferedReader` which is provided inside the java library.

> For any reason, if you do not want to project the usage of `scanner` then;

```
class MySpecialReader {

  private Scanner scanner;

  readData(){
     //use the scanner to read the data.
     //You can convert the checked exceptions to Runtime etc..
  }
}
```